# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings')

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I'm doing the exercise "sudoku" from the book "hello to android".
I saw some people have the same issue as me but I'm unable to solve it.
I have deleted three times this project and re-create from the beginning but I keep getting the same error message on below, even if I'm doing a copy/paste from the book.

```
W/ResourceType( 8592): Bad XML block: header size 29806 or total size 538970658 is larger than data size 0
    C:\java\Sudoku\res\layout\activity_main.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
C:\java\Sudoku\res\menu\activity_main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
```

There is the code inside the book for the `Sudokuv1/res/layout/main1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/main_title" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/continue_label" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/about_label" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/exit_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is the code for `Sudokuv1/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
<string name="main_title">Android Sudoku</string>
<string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
<string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
<string name="about_label">About</string>
<string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
</resources>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the issue is in the xml activity_main not the one you posted, it seems like it is looking for a string called hello_world and menu_settings which don't exist.

Comment: You have pasted the wrong xml. Check your error output.

Comment: show us activity_main.xml .... or simply add this to string.xml
<string name="hello_world">hi</string> and thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the android app with the Elcipse plugin, in the `res` folder you have a menu folder and inside that folder there is another `activity_mail.xml`.

Erase the file or comment its content since you wont be using the menu for the `sudoku app`.

That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

either add

```
<string name="hello_world">hi</string>
```

to your string.xml

or find the view called 'title' in your activity_main.xml and erase the android:text="@string/hello_world" property from it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `activity_main.xml` from `res>menu` because there are two files with the same name in `res>menu` and `res>layout`.